# How do I "sharpen" the edge of the path in the image with Stroke Path?

Tags: drawing, gimp, stroke, miter

I'm trying to use the stroke path function on a jagged path as shown in the image. I'd prefer to keep the line width, cap style, join style the same. I've tried adjusting the miter limit, going all the way to 100, but i'm still getting that rounded edge at the bottom left corner of the path. Compared to the right side, it is noticeably different.

I've already tried adjusting all the settings in the stroke path section, even changing my path, increasing the angle of the corner, etc but nothing works. Any ideas?

[image: Rounded edges from Stroke path on the right corner]

Answer (score 0):

The slight glitch right next to your rounded corner hints that the real problem is not an improper rendering, but very likely a very small path feature (small tangent generating a tiny loop or cusp, for instance). Try to zoom in 256x and use the path tool to remove it.

You can also use the [`ofn-remove-tangents` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) to remove these small tangents.